# Can you get a number from doing maths with a NaN?

Tags: java, math, nan

Say I had `double x = 0.0/0.0;`.

Is there anything I could do with `x` in order to get an actual number?

Dividing by itself/0/infinity? Subtracting by something? Anything like that.

Comment: Just prepare a sample program and try to do it yourself and see the output

Comment: You could assign a new value to x.  That's about it, I think.

Comment: @dbw just because I couldn't find a way to do it doesn't mean it's not possible it's easy to miss things, and that's why I've asked this question...

Answer (score 3):

You can go through each [JLS chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) for each of `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%` and you'll read

> If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN.

Using the value `NaN` with any of those would always produce `NaN`.

---

> Is there anything I could do with `x` in order to get an actual number?

I'm assuming you meant with the operators above.

Comment: what do you mean by your last point? Other operations are okay too, like square root and power and abs

Comment: @Aequitas There are no operators for those. They are implemented through methods and you can make methods do anything you want. You'll have to be more precise about _anything I could do with x_.

Answer (score -2):

I think, we should prevent any number divided by zero instead.

**EDIT**

```
avg = 0;
count = 0;
for (number in scores) {
     avg += number;
     count++;
}
if (count != 0){
    return avg / count;
} else {
    return 0.0;
}
```